# PHP, PCNTL and queue in shared memory

Tags: php, queue, shared-memory, pcntl

I'm having trouble with implementation of shared memory in php. Is it possible to make queue in shared memory?

Code is here:

```
// queue class
class AddressQueue extends \Nette\Object {

private $queue = array();

public function add($var) {
    $this->queue[] = $var;
}

public function get() {
    return array_shift($this->queue);
}

public function num() {
    return count($this->queue);
}
}

$segmentKey = "987654";
$permissions = 0666;
$size = 8092;
$sharedSegment = shm_attach($segmentKey, $size, $permissions);

shm_put_var($sharedSegment, QUEUE_INDEX, new AddressQueue());
```

...at this point, how can I add an item (int or very short string) to queue? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would get it back out using `shm_get_var()`, but there's no point in doing that, just add it before you use `shm_put_var()` like so:

```
$addrQueue = new AddressQueue();
$addrQueue->add('whatever');
shm_put_var($sharedSegment, QUEUE_INDEX, $addrQueue);
```

Comment: I need parent process to add items to the end of the queue and child processes to get items from the beginning at the same time :-(

Comment: Well then use `shm_get_var()`, that's the whole point of using shared memory :)